# presto sql to compare columns of different tables and filter out unmatched ones

Tags: sql, presto

I have a 2 tables
**user_activity**

```
user_id  activity_time
1        2020-10-10    
1        2020-10-09
```

**user_notification**

```
user_id  notification_time
1        2020-10-10    
1        2020-10-09
1        2020-10-08
```

looking for sql to compare activity_time in user_activity with notification_time in user_notification by using user_id and filter out records that won't have a match in **user_activity** table.
result from above example should be `1        2020-10-08`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `left join`, for instance:

```
select un.*
from user_notifications un left join
     user_activity ua 
     on ua.user_id = un.user_id and ua.activity_time = un.notification_time
where au.user_id is null;
```